# Consume JSON body, not form data

Tags: python

This is my Python. The input to it is

```
curl http://35.173.47.24:8090/put -d {"id":102} -X PUT
```

My code:

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_restful import Resource, Api

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

todos = {}
class TodoSimple(Resource):
    def put(self):
        i=request.form['id']
        print(i)
api.add_resource(TodoSimple, '/put')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=8090,debug=True)
```

I need to pass json parameter. What do I have to change?

Comment: {
    "message": "The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand."
}

Comment: If you have additional information, [edit] your question; don't add it to comments.

Comment: Please pick a more useful title for your question, and explain in the question itself what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

issue resolved issue was with code . request.get_json should be used

Answer (score 1):

change the request to

```
curl -X PUT http://25.173.47.24:8080/put -d '{"id":102}' -H "Content-Type:application/json"
```

Comment: Still failing[root@ip-172-31-77-17 ~]# curl http://35.173.47.24:8090/put -d {"id":102} -X PUT -H "Content-Type:application/json"
{
    "message": "The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand."
}
[root@ip-172-31-77-17 ~]#

Comment: issue resolved issue was with code . request.get_json should be used